# Where to put common writable application files?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, uac, application-data

I thought that `CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA\company\product` should be the place to put files that are common for all users of the application and that the application can modify, however, on Vista this is a read-only location, unless modified by the installer (as per MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995853.aspx), so... what's best? Modify the location's security settings to allow writing or use `CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS\company\product` instead? Maybe there's a third option?

Also, is there an "official" Microsoft recommendation on this somewhere?

Answer (score 15):

Modify just the security on a specific sub-directory of the AppData directory (this is from [the link you provided](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995853.aspx)):

> CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA This folder
>   should be used for application data
>   that is not user specific. For
>   example, an application may store a
>   spell check dictionary, a database of
>   clip-art or a log file in the
>   CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA folder. This
>   information will not roam and is
>   available to anyone using the
>   computer. By default, this location is
>   read-only for normal (non-admin,
>   non-power) Users. **If an application
>   requires normal Users to have write
>   access to an application specific
>   subdirectory of CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA,
>   then the application must explicitly
>   modify the security on that
>   sub-directory during application
>   setup.** The modified security must be
>   documented in the Vendor
>   Questionnaire.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm thinking as well. But it does seem like they (Microsoft) don't want you to put files in there and instead use the COMMON_DOCUMENTS one. Thanks.

Comment: Where do you get that they don't want you to put files there? It looks like they are quite happy with you putting files there - you should put them in your own sub-directory, and manage the security correctly.

Comment: I suppose so, but modifying the security is an extra step that I assume (perhaps wrongly) is placed there to discourage people from using this folder for writable files.

Comment: No it's an extra step to ensure that app data files remain isolated from each other. You are then forced to think about what users should have access and give it accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple example showing how to create files and folders with Read/Write permission for all users in the Common App Data folder (CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA). Any user can run this code to give all other users permission to write to the files & folders:

```
#include <windows.h>

#include <shlobj.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "shell32.lib")

// for PathAppend
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")

#include <stdio.h>
#include <aclapi.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "advapi32.lib")    

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DWORD dwRes, dwDisposition;
    PSID pEveryoneSID = NULL;
    PACL pACL = NULL;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = NULL;
    EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea;
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SIDAuthWorld = SECURITY_WORLD_SID_AUTHORITY;
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SIDAuthNT = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;

    // Create a well-known SID for the Everyone group.
    if (!AllocateAndInitializeSid(&SIDAuthWorld, 1,
                     SECURITY_WORLD_RID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                     &pEveryoneSID))
    {
        _tprintf(_T("AllocateAndInitializeSid Error %u\n"), GetLastError());
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    // Initialize an EXPLICIT_ACCESS structure for an ACE.
    // The ACE will allow Everyone access to files & folders you create.
    ZeroMemory(&ea, sizeof(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
    ea.grfAccessPermissions = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    ea.grfAccessMode = SET_ACCESS;

    // both folders & files will inherit this ACE
    ea.grfInheritance= CONTAINER_INHERIT_ACE|OBJECT_INHERIT_ACE;
    ea.Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
    ea.Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP;
    ea.Trustee.ptstrName  = (LPTSTR) pEveryoneSID;

    // Create a new ACL that contains the new ACEs.
    dwRes = SetEntriesInAcl(1, &ea, NULL, &pACL);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("SetEntriesInAcl Error %u\n"), GetLastError());
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    // Initialize a security descriptor.
    pSD = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR) LocalAlloc(LPTR, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH);
    if (NULL == pSD)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("LocalAlloc Error %u\n"), GetLastError());
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    if (!InitializeSecurityDescriptor(pSD, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION))
    {
        _tprintf(_T("InitializeSecurityDescriptor Error %u\n"), GetLastError());
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    // Add the ACL to the security descriptor.
    if (!SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(pSD,
            TRUE,     // bDaclPresent flag
            pACL,
            FALSE))   // not a default DACL
    {
        _tprintf(_T("SetSecurityDescriptorDacl Error %u\n"), GetLastError());
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    // Initialize a security attributes structure.
    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = pSD;
    sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;



    TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];

    if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA|CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE, NULL, 0, szPath))) 
    {
        PathAppend(szPath, TEXT("Your Shared Folder"));

        if (!CreateDirectory(szPath, &sa)
            && GetLastError() != ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS) 
        {
            goto Cleanup;
        }

        PathAppend(szPath, TEXT("textitup.txt"));

        HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(szPath, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, &sa, CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, 0);
        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            goto Cleanup;
        else
            CloseHandle(hFile);

        //TODO: do the writing
        ofstream fsOut;
        fsOut.exceptions(ios::eofbit | ios::failbit | ios::badbit);
        fsOut.open(szPath, ios::out | ios::binary | ios::trunc);

        fsOut << "Hello world!\n";
        fsOut.close();
    }

Cleanup:

    if (pEveryoneSID) 
        FreeSid(pEveryoneSID);
    if (pACL) 
        LocalFree(pACL);
    if (pSD) 
        LocalFree(pSD);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think [this post](http://lists.runrev.com/pipermail/use-revolution/2007-February/094217.html) may answer some questions, but it seems a difficult problem for many.

Apparently, CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS provides a common workaround

Comment: Sorry, I fail to see how that answers the question. I know how to get the path, I'm asking what's the proper path to get.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Too bad there's no official answer to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Guidelines for Vista/UAC can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530410.aspx). Search that page for "`CSIDL`" and you'll find some "official" answers.

Comment: Thanks - it all points to the directory I was originally planning to use. I guess it's the right answer then :)

Comment: It's a nice warm feeling finding out that you were right all along, isn't it? ;-)