# Where do I store files on Vista/Win7 for all users with read/write permission

Tags: delphi, windows-7, windows-vista

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to put common writable application files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147016/where-to-put-common-writable-application-files)

In my application I have some setting-files, which needs read/write permission and should be accessable by all users.

So far I found in the net is, that microsoft gives you some special folders in Win Vista/7, but none of them fulfills my needs: 
1) CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA => C:\ProgramData, has no write permission 
2) CSIDL_APPDATA => is user specifc 
3) CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA => is user specific

How can I access such folder, which contains APP DATA, is accessable by all users and has read/write permission?

Comment: Why have you designed a program where any non-administrative user would be able to overwrite some data and ruin the experience for all the other users?

Comment: in most cases shared customer data, when not a db is used.

Comment: [Where to put common writable application files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/147016) may give some pointers.

Comment: These are data which belong to the application, independet who is using it. Furthermore, I don't want to create settings files and folders for every user profile on the computer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

on a system wide installation, you have to write them to CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA.
but you have also to set the permissions within your setup.

don't give rights to "everybody" - "authenticated" is better

if you are using windows installer, then you have to take care of users and system installations. if it is a user installation, you have to write to the CSIDL_APPDATA or CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA (depending of roaming or not roaming data).

If you understand german take a look in the entwickler magazin 3.2011.
there will be a article "Einstellungssache", which is on topic.

[MSDN - Data and Settings Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995853.aspx)

Comment: +1 CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA with permissions when running setup.