# SHGetFolderPath Deprecated: What is alternative to retrieve path for Windows folders?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, known-folders

The `SHGetFolderPath()` function is deprecated beginning with Windows Vista: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

What is the alternative way to retrieve the path to the Application Folder in Windows?

```
SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA, NULL, 0, szPath)
```

Aside from that, why do I get those errors when using this function:

```
Error   1   error C2065: 'CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA' : undeclared identifier 

Error   2   error C3861: 'SHGetFolderPath': identifier not found
```

Comment: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181(v=vs.85).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx and finally, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The alternative is described in the documentation to which you link. Namely it is [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188.aspx).

However, `SHGetKnownFolderPath` is only available on Vista or later. So if you use load time linking, and run a program that calls `SHGetKnownFolderPath` on XP, then that program will fail to start. This is clearly a problem if you wish to support XP.

Now, you could switch to run time linking of `SHGetKnownFolderPath`. Carry out a version check before you call it, and if the function is not available, then fall back to `SHGetFolderPath`.

Personally, I would not let this deprecation worry you excessively. Microsoft are renowned for maintaining backwards compatibility. Don't expect `SHGetFolderPath` to disappear any time soon. You will find that `SHGetFolderPath` exists in Windows 8 and I would expect it still to be present in whatever Windows is current 10 years from now. My advice is to stick to load time linking, and only switch to `SHGetKnownFolderPath` when you give up supporting XP.

Your other question, that you ask in an edit, is how to call `SHGetFolderPath`. You need to respect the requirements which are laid out at the bottom of the MSDN documentation topic which you linked to in your question. Specifically, include `Shlobj.h` and pass `Shlobj.lib` to the linker.

Comment: But How to get to the Application Data folder?

Comment: That's a totally different question. I updated the answer to cover it, but I would suggest that in future you keep to one question at a time.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - this is great explanation. I've updated some new VBA code that I'm writing targeting on OS Win 10+ platforms. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is linked right at the top, [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA is replaced by FOLDERID_ProgramData in the new API.

Comment: But How to get to the Application Data folder?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same set of errors when I added few new header files to my already working solution.

I was already calling `SHGetFolderPath` and had also included `#include <ShlObj.h>` but it was in a different header file. The solution was compiling without any errors before I added new library header files to it.

I tried replacing `SHGetFolderPath()` with `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` but this just redirected the **identifier not found** error to `SHGetKnownFolderPath`.

> On adding `#include <ShlObj.h>` to the header file of the class calling `SHGetFolderPath`, the
>   errors ceased and the solution compiled successfully again.

As mentioned in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpatha) page, calling `SHGetFolderPath` on Windows Vista or a higher OS, will internally call `SHGetKnownFolderPath`.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested using the `SHGetFolderPath()` with Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise on a Windows 10 PC and it compiled and worked just fine to find the current user's home folder. In the Windows Dev Center page on `SHGetFolderPath()` [SHGetFolderPath function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181(v=vs.85).aspx) there is the following note:

> **Note**  As of Windows Vista, this function is merely a wrapper for
>   `SHGetKnownFolderPath`. The `CSIDL` value is translated to its associated
>   `KNOWNFOLDERID` and then `SHGetKnownFolderPath` is called. New
>   applications should use the known folder system rather than the older
>   `CSIDL` system, which is supported only for backward compatibility.

As David Heffman pointed out in his answer, Microsoft has a history of keeping backwards compatibility for years especially when they can take the older function and just redirect it to the new function with the appropriate arguments. The `CSIDL` values seem to have a corresponding `KNOWNFOLDERID` value. See this [table of the `CSIDL` constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494(v=vs.85).aspx) with brief annotations and the corresponding `KNOWNFOLDERID` value.

An example of the use of the function follows. This use retrieves the current user's user folder (e.g. "C:\Users\myuser\Documents" under Windows 7) and then adds a folder name to the end of the path using the `PathAppend()` function.

```
TCHAR   achDevice[MAX_PATH];
HRESULT  hr;
// include file ShlObj.h contains list of CSIDL defines however only a subset
// are supported with Windows 7 and later.
// for the 3rd argument, hToken, can be a specified Access Token or SSID for
// a user other than the current user. Using NULL gives us the current user.
if (SUCCEEDED(hr = SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_PERSONAL, NULL, 0, achDevice))) {
    // append a folder name to the user's Documents directory.
    // the Path Handling functions are pretty handy.
    PathAppend(achDevice, L"xxx");
}
```

One possible failure is one or more invalid arguments (hr == `E_INVALIDARG`). A returned value of `S_OK` indicates the call succeeded.

There are a few `CSIDL` constants that can be used to modify the results of the function such as `CSIDL_FLAG_CREATE` by using the bitwise OR operator. I am not sure how well those operators will work with Windows 7 and later.

There are limits on the supported `CSIDL` constants with Windows 7 and later. It also looks like there may be possible issues to overcome in complex, remote mounted, redirected, and/or shared folders in an Active Directory or similar environment.

See also [KNOWNFOLDERID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457(v=vs.85).aspx) which includes a table that indicates some of the limitations of `CSIDL` and `SHGetFolderPath()`. Some examples from the table of `CSIDL` constants that may be useful.

```
CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA - %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local
CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS - %USERPROFILE%\Document
CSIDL_PERSONAL -    %USERPROFILE%\Documents
CSIDL_FONTS -       %windir%\Fonts
CSIDL_MYMUSIC -     %USERPROFILE%\Music
CSIDL_MYPICTURES -  %USERPROFILE%\Pictures
CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA - %ALLUSERSPROFILE% (%ProgramData%, %SystemDrive%\ProgramData)
CSIDL_COMMON_DOCUMENTS -    %PUBLIC%\Documents
```

By the way, the [Shell Path Handling Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773559(v=vs.85).aspx) are a nice library of methods for manipulating file paths.

See also [Where to put common writable application files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147016/where-to-put-common-writable-application-files)

Answer (score 0):

From microsoft, the altenate is "SHGetKnownFolderPath"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpatha

From my point of view, these functions are for c, c++ and similar languages.
From powershell, I just read the registry:
PS> cd hkcu:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\
PS> dir

Here peek at "Shell Folders" and "User Shell Folders".

btw: These are for getting the values. I'd say that's fairly safe. For setting the values, better not use the registry direct, as it will ruin your day. Using the explorer -> properties of these 'directories' to move them, will also move the contents. Unfortunately, I donnot know a hook to use that in powershell.