# How to get 'My Document' folder path by python?

Tags: python, pywin32

My script is combined with 'My Document' folder, but I could not get the path of it on windows 7.

### First:

I followed [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227590/finding-the-users-my-documents-path)

```
os.path.expanduser(path)
```

But,as a comment said

> On Windows a os.path.expanduser('~/filename') call results in something like 'C:\Documents and Settings\/filename' which is not the path of something in the user's My Documents folder.

If user move his 'My Document' folder, this would not work.

### Then

I found another solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858851/python-get-windows-special-folders-for-currently-logged-in-user).
It seems works well with mypictures folder, but if I tried mydocuments I will got an error like:

```
>>> print(shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, shellcon.CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS, None, 0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    print(shell.SHGetFolderPath(0, shellcon.CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS, None, 0))
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147024809, 'argument error', None, None)
```

I was confused about that, so I googled another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493484/shgetfolderpath-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative) here.
It seems we should use `SHGetKnownFolderPath` function in windows7.
But I can't find this function in win32com.shell.

### Finally

I got a way that would work which answered below yet I got more question now.

Answer (score 1):

Now I found I should use the argument `shellcon.CSIDL_PERSONAL` instead of `shellcon.CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS` .
But I don't know why.

On MSDN the function is said to be deprecated, but it still in pywin32 and I could not found the alternative function `SHGetKnownFolderPath`.

Further more,[`CSIDL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is also been replaced by `KNOWNFOLDERID` values, and in [`CSIDL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) document `CSIDL_PERSONAL` is equal to `CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS`.

So what is the recommended way to get windows special folder now?